# Excel - VBA Insert Data From Raw File to Output File

Tags: excel, vba

Would like to ask if it is possible to create a condition in excel vba for inserting rows of matched values in output file

for example:

This is an example list of my student:

[image]

This one is for the checklist of their exams / questionnaires:

[image]

This would be the final output:

[image]

Is it possible for VBA to look like in the results file? I only figured out how to put the number series per TestLEVEL value. But still thinking how to insert the Questionnaire and Value columns exactly the way I want.

THANKS! hope it is possible

Comment: Welcome to SO! I am almost certain that it is indeed possible to do that. However, if you're asking us to do it for you, you've come to the wrong place. Try it for yourself first, [show us your attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and you might get some help.

Comment: @eirikdaude I'm just new in vba I'm a Math teacher. I tried the =INDEX(MATCH()) formula to get the matched value but it turns out it only gets the first matched value. I just discover abt VBA by surfing on net and I got interested to learn it since it will help to automate some of my files by using macro. I just know the basics one but not the advanced. Hope u guys can help me to figure it out. Thanks I'm also trying to figure it out. Since u says that it is possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further reflection, and assuming I have understood your requirements correctly, I think the easiest way to do this is by using the [`FILTER`-function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759). Note that this function is only available in Office 365, and that your argument separator might be a different one than mine.

It is also not ideal for automating the task since I assume the number of Questionnaire / Value pairs will be different from time to time. It is fairly simple to use though, so I guess it won't be a lot of work to create the formulas.

The way I did it was creating a duplicate of the second sheet you have a picture of into my workbook, and then create a sheet similar to the third one you have a picture of. In this sheet I put the formula

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$19;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$19=D2;NA())
```

into cell F2 and

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$19;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$19=D2;NA())
```

into G2.

The formula then fills the filtered range into the column as shown below:

[image]

To get the Questionnaire values of the student with student no. 4321 into range F8:F13, use the formula

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$19;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$19=D8;NA())
```

and so on.

I think this should solve your problem as presented in the question, at least, though your sheet will probably need a bit of editing if you have different input data.

As a further tip, I would recommend changing your data to tables when that is what they basically are anyway, it makes referencing them a bit simpler.

I hope this was of some help to you, don't hesitate to ask if something seems unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) and [FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) to match the Student No and Test Levels on the 2 sheets.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub MyMacro()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsName As Worksheet, wsExam As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngNo As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Long, r As Long, rOut As Long
    Dim n As Integer, m As Integer, i As Long
    Dim sNo As String, sTest As String, sFirstFind As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsName = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsExam = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngNo = wsExam.UsedRange.Columns("A:A") ' student no
    
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
    wsOut.Cells.Clear
    i = 1 ' col A no
    n = 0 ' block row for Col B-F
    m = 0 ' block row for Col G-H
   
    rOut = 2
    iLastRow = wsName.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To iLastRow

        sTest = wsName.Cells(r, "D")
        sNo = wsName.Cells(r, "C")

        ' start new block if no or test different to previous row
        If sNo <> wsName.Cells(r - 1, "C") _
           Or sTest <> wsName.Cells(r - 1, "D") Then
            ' align columns
            If m > n Then
                rOut = rOut + m
            Else
                rOut = rOut + n
            End If
            n = 0
            m = 0
          
            ' start new test
            sTest = wsName.Cells(r, "D")
            If sTest <> wsName.Cells(r - 1, "D") Then
                wsOut.Cells(rOut, "A") = i
                i = i + 1
            End If

            ' search for matching Student No
            Set rng = rngNo.Find(sNo, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If rng Is Nothing Then
            Else
                sFirstFind = rng.Address
                Do
                    'is testlevel the same
                    If rng.Offset(0, 4) = sTest Then
                        ' copy col C-D to G-H
                        rng.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 2).Copy wsOut.Cells(rOut + m, "G")
                        m = m + 1
                    End If
                    ' find next
                    Set rng = rngNo.FindNext(rng)
                Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And rng.Address <> sFirstFind
            End If
        End If
        ' copy col A-E to col B-F
        wsName.Cells(r, "A").Resize(1, 5).Copy wsOut.Cells(rOut + n, "B")
        n = n + 1
    Next
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
End Sub
```